# question on how to junit test using Mockito forEach in Java8

Tags: junit, mockito

I have the below method and I need to unit test it using JUNIT and Mockito. I am confused how to test the foreach method which returns void.

```
public  List<Data> extractOutPutResponse(List<SearchHit> searchHits) {

    List<Data> outputData = new ArrayList<>();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    searchHits.forEach(hit -> outputData.add(gson.fromJson(hit.getSourceAsString(), Data.class)));
    return outputData;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to use `mockito` for this? This method does not seem to use any dependencies and mocking the parameter does not seem to be necessary as you can easily create a list.

Comment: In a more general case you might want to use `Mockito.doAnswer(...).when(mock).forEach(Mockito.any(Consumer.class));`

Comment: The class SearchHit is an immutable class, so creating a list without Mocking is probably not possible.  I will try the doAnswer as suggested.

Comment: How is `an immutable class` related to `creating a list`?

Comment: How else will create a List of SearchHit? Either I have to mock SearchHit or I have to pass Null?

Comment: Assuming your are talking about elasticsearch's `SearcHit` class, maybe you wanted to say the class is `final` (and not `immutable`)? In that case you can enable final mocking for mockito (as described [here](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.2.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#39)).